# How to write this code better in kivy/python

Tags: python, kivy

so I have been trying to make this app that features a list of buttons on each page that navigate to other pages with buttons then each page leads to an image.  I feel that I am being very inefficient with my button placement/usage but I don't know how to manage it any other way.  Here is a sample of the code:

.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class HomePage(Screen):
    pass

class AdminPage(Screen):
    pass

class AdultPage(Screen):
    pass

class PedsPage(Screen):
    pass

class OBPage(Screen):
    pass

class DeceasedPage(Screen):
    pass

class FirePage(Screen):
    pass

class MedsPage(Screen):
    pass

class MyApp(App): # <- Main Class
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,0)

        sm = ScreenManager()

        ###### main
        
        sm.add_widget(HomePage(name="HomePage"))
        sm.add_widget(Back(name="Back"))
        sm.add_widget(HomeBtn(name="HomeBtn"))
        sm.add_widget(AdultPage(name="AdultPage"))
        sm.add_widget(AdultRespirPage(name="AdultRespirPage"))
        sm.add_widget(AdminPage(name="AdminPage"))
        sm.add_widget(DeceasedPage(name='DeceasedPage'))
        sm.add_widget(PedsPage(name="PedsPage"))
        sm.add_widget(MedsPage(name="MedsPage"))

        return sm
```

then the .kv file:

```
<HomePage>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: (40,0,40,0)
        spacing: 10

        Button:

            text_size: self.width, None
            halign: "center"
            text: "Administrative"
            background_color: 1.65,1.65,1.65,1
            on_press: root.manager.current = "AdminPage"

        Button:
            text: "Adult Patients"
            spacing: 100
            on_press: root.manager.current = "AdultPage"
            background_color: .6,2.35,0.26,1
        Button:
            text: "Pediatric Patients"
            spacing: 100
            on_press: root.manager.current = "PedsPage"
            background_color: 2.55, 1.26, 0.25,1
        Button:
            text: "Obstetrical Patients"
            spacing: 100
            on_press: root.manager.current = "OBPage"
            background_color: 2.47,.12,2.31,1
        Button:
            text: "Deceased Patients"
            spacing: 100
            on_press: root.manager.current = "DeceasedPage"
            background_color: 0,0,0,1
        Button:
            text: "Fire Fighter Rehab"
            spacing: 100
            on_press: root.manager.current = "FirePage"
            background_color: 2.47,0,0,1
        Button:
            text: "Medications Guide"
            spacing: 100
            on_press: root.manager.current = "MedsPage"
            background_color: 0,0,2.47,1
```

when I run the code it crashes on a certain page and gives a "out of memory" report in the logcat, and the sample above is only a small portion of the code I have written.

thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: Please remember to look at your post after submitting, and then edit it to fix any markup mistakes.  Also note that if you code _works_, and you just help refactoring it, Stackoverflow is [not the right place](/help/on-topic) to ask, and you'll want to ask for refactoring help over on https://codereview.stackexchange.com instead. However, if you need help debugging that crash, then tailor your post's text and the code you show specifically to that, ideally by phrasing things in terms of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like to keep as much design as possible in the kv file and the logic in the .py/python file, that just makes it easier to search for errors and understand what is happening in your program.